# How can I edit the projectile-known-projects list?

Tags: projectile

Is it possible to edit the projectile-known-projects as a list?

In the same manner I do with org-agenda-files, which can be edited in the list with INS and DEL.

I've tried describe-variable, but there is no list there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *is* a list.

It's not a user option though (i.e. it's defined with `defvar` rather than `defcustom`), so there's no customize UI for it.

As such, you have to edit it in lisp.